# How to do join in ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I am new to Entity Framework. I have a model as given below.

[image]

Since I need to access this from Silverlight I have added a `DomainService`

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
    public class DomainService1 : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<TESTDBEntities>
    {
        public IQueryable<Lecture> GetLectures()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Lectures;
        }      
        public IQueryable<ProjectGroup> GetProjectGroups()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.ProjectGroups;
        }
        public IQueryable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Students;
        }
    }
```

I need to add a method to the domain service that returns `List<Student>` for a given project group id.

`List<Student> GetStudentsByProject(int pgid)`

OR

`IQueryable<Student> GetStudentsByProject(int pgid)`

Since this involves a join, I guess I have to change the `Model.edmx` as well as `DomainService.cs` file manually. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change the .edmx file.

```
public List<Student> GetStudentsByProject(int pgid)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.ProjectGroup.Where(pg => pg.pgid == pgid)
               .SelectMany(pg => pg.Students).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Selecting the students through a query to ProjectGroup like in your example will probably result in a very complicated SQL statement containing sub-selects an union statements. Compared to a simple `ObjectContext.Students.Where(x => x.ProjectGroup.pgid == projectGroupId)` it produces ca. 7 times(!) as much SQL code.

Comment: I have changed the query to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`, which will produce a much less complex SQL.

Comment: Why not just get the Students with the given Projectgroup Id directly?

Comment: @DennisTraub Doing what you suggest is of course perfectly good. I prefer to start at the top and find that more intuitive. At least for more complex queries. For this you could also write `ObjectContext.ProjectGroup.FirstOrDefault(pg => pg.pgid == pgid).Students` which I find equally intuitive, but it is a matter of taste I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another method to your domain service and you should be fine:

```
public IQueryable<Student> GetStudentsByGroup(int projectGroupId)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Students
               .Where(x => x.ProjectGroup.pgid == projectGroupId);
}
```